# How to allow timer to keep running in the background

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17

I am writing a program for my club. The users are asked to answer 10 questions within 2 minutes. I am using functions for each questions and by calling the next function when the user finished answering the current question. How can i display the remaining time on top while at the same time displaying the question?

I have tried loop to control my time. But it will not show the remaining time on top and display the question at the same time as the loop will need to execute until the condition is false

```
Question1()
{
countdown();
cout<<"Question 1 out of 10"<<endl<<endl;
cout<<" Where Is The First Indoor Bowling Lane Built? "<<endl;
cout<<"A. New York City"<<endl;
cout<<"B. Berlin"<<endl;
cout<<"C. Ohio"<<endl;
cout<<"D. Japan"<<endl;
cout<<"Your answer: ";                                                                                                                       
cin>>ans1;
Question2();
}
void countdown()
{
while(timer>=0)
{
cout<<"Time remaining: "<<timer<<endl;
Sleep(1000);
timer--;
system("cls");
}
}
```

Expected time to be counting down on top of my questions but the questions only shows up until the time set is over.

Comment: You need to either use a thread for your timer routine, or use system timers.  If you want the expired timer to cancel input and move to the next question, then you'll need something like [PeekConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/peekconsoleinput) and other console routines (assuming you are using Windows, given your call to `Sleep`).  These topics are a little advanced.  You will need to experiment with them individually, and find examples online to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I thought back to the days of MS-DOS, and remembered there is a function `_kbhit` provided by `<conio.h>` in Windows.  It is not portable, but maybe you don't care.  Here is a function I knocked up that will use `_kbhit` to poll for a keypress.  It's rough as guts, but maybe that's what you're looking for.

```
int GetInputWithTimeout(int count, int timeout)
{
    int answer = -1;
    const int poll_rate = 10;
    int poll_cycle = 0, last_timeout = 0;
    do {
        // poll for keypress and store answer if valid
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            int input = _getch();
            while (_kbhit()) _getch(); // discard control sequences
            input = tolower(input);
            if (input >= 'a' && input < 'a' + count)
            {
                answer = input - 'a';
            }
        }

        // display time remaining if changed
        if (last_timeout != timeout) {
            last_timeout = timeout;
            std::cout << "\rTime remaining: " << timeout << " " << std::flush;
        }

        // perform small sleeps for a potentially wildly inaccurate, but responsive delay
        if (timeout > 0)
        {
            Sleep(1000 / poll_rate);
            poll_cycle = (poll_cycle + 1) % poll_rate;
            if (poll_cycle == 0) --timeout;
        }
    } while (timeout > 0 && answer == -1);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return answer;
}
```

So you can use this function, passing the desired number of quiz inputs.  Suggested use is something like this:

```
struct Question {
    std::string question;
    std::vector<std::string> answers;
    int correct_answer;
    int timeout_seconds = 10;
};

bool AskQuestion(int number, const Question& question)
{
    std::cout << "Question " << number << ": " << question.question << std::endl;
    int count = static_cast<int>(question.answers.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "  " << char('A' + i) << ": " << question.answers[i] << std::endl;
    }
    int answer = GetInputWithTimeout(count, question.timeout_seconds);
    return answer == question.correct_answer;
}
```

You'll notice I've represented a single quiz question in a struct.  And so you can set up and run the entire quiz like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Question> questions = {
        {
            "Where Is The First Indoor Bowling Lane Built?",
            {
                "New York City",
                "Berlin",
                "Ohio",
                "Japan"
            },
            0, // I have no idea, so just guessed it's new york
        },
        {
            "What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?",
            {
                "10km/h",
                "20km/h",
                "30km/h",
                "40km/h",
                "What do you mean -- an african or european swallow?"
            },
            4,
        },
    };

    int num_questions = static_cast<int>(questions.size());
    int num_correct = 0;    
    for (int q = 0; q < num_questions; q++)
    {
        num_correct += AskQuestion(q, questions[q]);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Final score: " << num_correct << " of " << num_questions << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Err, whoops I kinda wrote the whole program for you.  It's not pretty, but hopefully that at least teaches you something.